# Query using regular expression and subselect is too slow

Tags: mysql

I have this query in my PHP code hitting a MySQL 5.5 database.  The purpose of this query is to generate the next invoice number, so I need to make sure I get the max existing invoice number and add 1 to it.

The trick is that this reference (invoice #) column is a varchar so the users can enter alpha numeric characters, so my query needs to look only at the numeric values.

```
select max(cast(t.reference as unsigned)) reference
                  from transactions t, families f
                 where t.familyid in (select id from families where companyid = 1415)
                   and t.familyid = f.id
                   and transactiontype = 'C'
                   and t.reference REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

As you can see I'm using a regular expression because what I'm trying to do is get the largest number currently existing in the reference column, in order to generate the next invoice number.

The current query takes anywhere from 2 to 8 seconds until it's cached.  Is there any way to speed this up, or is that as good as it gets?

Comment: How are your indexes set up, usually when you're dealing with slow queries, it's an indexing issue.

Comment: It also looks like you've got your data model set up in a very strange way.

Comment: Strange in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this, removed in clause overhead:

```
select max(cast(t.reference as unsigned)) reference
                 from transactions t, families f
                 where 
                   t.familyid = f.id
                   and f.companyid = 1415
                   and t.transactiontype = 'C'
                   and t.reference REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: That is much faster.  Thank you!